# annotate gem not working after including custom module inside model

Tags: ruby

After i include custom module inside model, annotate stop working and give me error:
My model: app/models/hotel.rb

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include HotelHandler
  
  ...

end
```

Custom helper class: app/helpers/hotel_handler.rb

```
module HotelHandler
  ...
end
```

This give me error:

> uninitialized constant Hotel::HotelHandler (NameError)

Comment: does it still give you the error if you do `include ::HotelHandler`?

Comment: yes, it still give me same error

Comment: How dd you name the file containing the `HotelHandler` and where did you place it?

Comment: file path app/helpers/hotel_handler.rb

Comment: its ruby project, i am not using rails. Canu suggest me how to eager load in ruby. I tried adding ActiveRecord::Base.eager_load = true

Comment: got into this: cannot load such file -- helpers/hotel_handler (LoadError)

Comment: After requiring 'hotel_handler' and including "include HotelHandler" in model. stil run into same error: `<class:Hotel>': uninitialized constant Hotel::HotelHandler (NameError)

Comment: try `require_relative '../helpers/hotel_handler'`

Comment: If it's not a Rails project you probably don't have autoloader set up (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html), what you need is ti require or set up the autoloader for your app (out of scope of this question)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to setup Rails style auto and eager loading in a plain old Ruby project the modern way is to use [Zeitwerk](https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk):

```
# this file would be the "entry path" to your application such as config.ru

# loads an installs gems inline
require 'bundler/inline'

gemfile do
  source 'https://rubygems.org'
  gem 'zeitwerk'
end

root = Pathname.new(File.expand_path(__dir__))
env = ENV.fetch("MYAPP_ENV", 'development')
loader = Zeitwerk::Loader.new

# Mimics Rails by adding every subdirectory of `/app` and `/app/**/concerns` 
# as "root directories" where zeitwerk will find top level constants
paths = [
  dir[root.join('app/*/')]
  dir[root.join('app/**/concerns')]
].flatten.each do |path|
  loader.push_dir(path) if File.directory?(path)
end

# makes zeitwerk reload classes when they change
loader.enable_reloading if env == 'development'
loader.setup
# loads all classes on boot for performance
loader.eager_load if env == 'production'
```

This is really just a quick and dirty minimal example and you would usually enscapsulate this logic into a bootstapping file and an "Application" class.